# call a static JNI method to return a String from C++

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to call the following java method in Android

```
public static String getLevelFile(String levelName) { /*body*/}
```

from c++ using the following jni code

```
JniMethodInfoJavaApi methodInfo;

    if (! getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "getLevelFile", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;"))
        {
            return std::string("");
        }
    LOGD("calling getLevelFile");
    jstring returnString = (jstring) methodInfo.env->CallStaticObjectMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID, levelName.c_str());
    LOGD("returned from getLevelFile");
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);

    const char *js = methodInfo.env->GetStringUTFChars(returnString, NULL);
    std::string cs(js);
    methodInfo.env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(returnString, js);
    LOGD("returning Level data");
```

The app crashes when doing the `CallStaticMethodObject()` . I have verified that the method signature is correct by using `javap`. And the `LOGD("calling getLevelFile");` prints fine and then it crashes. I am able to do other `CallStaticVoidMethod()`s from the same class but not this one. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Been quite a while since I used JNI, but I'm fairly sure that you can't pass the result of `c_str()` to a Java method but instead need to create a `jstring` to pass in.

Comment: Yup.  Create the string from MUTF-8 or UTF-16 with `NewStringUTF` or `NewString`.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimIsaksson . It worked. If you would put it as an answer, I would to happy to mark as correct and upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly pass a nul terminated string (returned from `c_str()`) as a parameter to a Java/JNI method.

To pass it to the method, create a `jstring` from the nul terminated string (for example using `NewStringUTF`) and pass that instead.

Answer (score 5):

You're in luck, Java and Android both use the Unicode character set. However, Android (by default) use the UTF-8 encoding, which JNI doesn't intrisically support. Nonetheless, Java classes are fully capable of converting between character set encodings. The `lang.java.String` constructors allow you to specify a character set/encoding or use the OS-default, which on Android, of course, is coded as UTF-8.

To make it easier (I prefer coding in Java, minimizing code that calls the JNI library), create an overload of your method and do some of the implementation in Java:

```
private static byte[] getLevelFile(byte[] levelName) {
    return getLevelFile(new String(levelName)).getBytes();
}
```

Now the JNI code only has to deal with jbytearray, both for the parameter and the return value:

```
JniMethodInfoJavaApi methodInfo;

if (! getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "getLevelFile", "([B)[B"))
{
    return std::string("");
}

LOGD("calling getLevelFile");

int nameLength = levelName.length();
jbyteArray nameBytes = methodInfo.env->NewByteArray(nameLength);
methodInfo.env->SetByteArrayRegion(nameBytes, 0, nameLength, reinterpret_cast<const jbyte*>(levelName.c_str()));

jbyteArray returnString = (jbyteArray) methodInfo.env->CallStaticObjectMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID, nameBytes);
LOGD("returned from getLevelFile");
methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(nameBytes);

int returnLength = methodInfo.env->GetArrayLength(returnString);
std::string data;
data.reserve(returnLength);
methodInfo.env->GetByteArrayRegion(returnString, 0, returnLength, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(&data[0]));
methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(returnString);

LOGD("returning Level data");
return data;
```