# Scala application using Java SWIG-wrapped C++ code crashes

Tags: java, c++, scala, swig

EDIT: Following advice below, I changed char* to std::string and updated everything as required (listed below). Problem is still in place.

I've used SWIG 3.0 to wrap a simple C++ class for java, and I am using it in Scala. I am working on a Centos 7.1 machine.

I used the following command to run SWIG:

```
swig -java -c++ -package pkg -outdir pkg -o jocr.cpp jocr.i
```

The relevant files are:

jocr.i:

```
%module jocr
%{
#include "Ocr.h"
%}
%include "std_string.i"
#include <string>
class Ocr {
public:
    std::string process(std::string req);
};
```

Ocr.h:

```
#ifndef OCR_H_
#define OCR_H_
#include <string>
class Ocr {
public:
    std::string process(std::string request);
};

#endif /* OCR_H_ */
```

The Ocr:process method receives a json string which contains a file name for download, downloads the file using curl, performs OCR processing on the file using tesseract and leptonica, and returns a json string containing the ocr results. Ocr is handled by the latest version of Nlohmann's json class.

The java file that I use in the Scala application, to wrap the JNI:

```
public class CPPWrapper{
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("curl");
        System.loadLibrary("lept");
        System.loadLibrary("tesseract");
        System.loadLibrary("OCRLib"); // My c++ code in shared object
    }

    public static String process(String image) {
        Ocr ocr = new Ocr();

        String result = ocr.process(image);

        System.out.println("CPPWrapper result: " + result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

EDIT: The makefile I am using to make the C++ shared object is:

```
all: jocr.cpp libOCRLib.so

OBJS = IPUtil.o OutputFormatter.o NlohmannJsonWrapper.o Ocr.o jocr.o
CC = g++
DEBUG = -g
CFLAGS = -Wall -c $(DEBUG) -fPIC
LFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG)
INCLUDES = -I/usr/local/include:/usr/include -I/opt/jdk/include -I/opt/jdk/include/linux
LIBS = -ltesseract -llept -lcurl
LIBDIR = -L/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib

libOCRLib.so : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) $(OBJS) -shared -Wl,-soname,OCRLib.so -o libOCRLib.so

IPUtil.o : IPUtil.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -fpermissive IPUtil.cpp

Ocr.o : Ocr.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) Ocr.cpp


jocr.o : jocr.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -fpermissive jocr.cpp

OutputFormatter.o : OutputFormatter.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -fpermissive -std=c++11 OutputFormatter.cpp

NlohmannJsonWrapper.o : NlohmannJsonWrapper.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -fpermissive -std=c++11 NlohmannJsonWrapper.cpp

clean:
    \rm -r com/vatbox/ocr/*.* *.o *.so jocr.cpp
jocr.cpp: 
    swig -java -c++ -package com.vatbox.ocr -outdir com/vatbox/ocr -o jocr.cpp jocr.i

install:
    cp -R com ../../../vatbox/OCRProcessingService/app/
```

The Scala code runs a thread pool of workers each of which creates the above class and uses the method.

After some time of running, which is directly affected by the number of threads in the pool (the more = the sooner the crash), this is the error I get: 
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f7855da4a5a, pid=13191, tid=140151558756096
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_91-b14) (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.91-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [libc.so.6+0x8aa5a]  strlen+0x2a

A log file is also generated, but was too long to paste here, so I've pasted the highlights below.

I've scoured google for a similar problem, but the only two places I found had different circumstances which didn't help me.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Error log highlights:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f7855da4a5a, pid=13191, tid=140151558756096
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_91-b14) (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.91-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x8aa5a]  strlen+0x2a
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/ec2-user/vatbox/OCRProcessingService/core or core.13191
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f7794006800):  JavaThread "ForkJoinPool-2-worker-13" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=13255, stack(0x00007f7793cfd000,0x00007f7793dfe000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr: 0x00007f7771eee178

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00007f7771eee178: <offset 0x6c178> in /home/ec2-user/workspace/OCRLib/src/libOCRLib.so at 0x00007f7771e82000
RBX=0x00007f7771eee178: <offset 0x6c178> in /home/ec2-user/workspace/OCRLib/src/libOCRLib.so at 0x00007f7771e82000
RCX=0x0000000000000178 is an unknown value
RDX=0xffffffffffffffff is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f7793dfbdc8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f7794006800
RBP=0x00007f7793dfbe40 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f7794006800
RSI=0x00007f7771eee178: <offset 0x6c178> in /home/ec2-user/workspace/OCRLib/src/libOCRLib.so at 0x00007f7771e82000
RDI=0x00007f7771eee178: <offset 0x6c178> in /home/ec2-user/workspace/OCRLib/src/libOCRLib.so at 0x00007f7771e82000
R8 =0x00007f7793dfc110 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f7794006800
R9 =0x00007f7793dfc130 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f7794006800
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13={method} {0x00007f77f0d4f118} 'Ocr_process' '(JLcom/vatbox/ocr/Ocr;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;' in 'com/vatbox/ocr/jocrJNI'
R14=0x00007f7793dfc4f8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f7794006800
R15=0x00007f7794006800 is a thread


Stack: [0x00007f7793cfd000,0x00007f7793dfe000],  sp=0x00007f7793dfbdc8,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0x8aa5a]  strlen+0x2a
C  0x0000000001276000
C  0x0000000000020000

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.vatbox.ocr.jocrJNI.Ocr_process(JLcom/vatbox/ocr/Ocr;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+0
j  com.vatbox.ocr.Ocr.process(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+6
j  com.vatbox.ocr.CPPWrapper.process(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+10
j  service.Processor$$anonfun$process$1.apply()Ljava/lang/String;+4
j  service.Processor$$anonfun$process$1.apply()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1()Lscala/util/Try;+8
j  scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run()V+5
j  scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec()Z+4
j  scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec()I+10
j  scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecAll()V+10
j  scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Lscala/concurrent/forkjoin/ForkJoinTask;)V+56
j  scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Lscala/concurrent/forkjoin/ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue;)V+11
j  scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run()V+14
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub


VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Didea.launcher.port=7533 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/ec2-user/IntelliJ/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner -s service.ProcessingServiceSpec -showProgressMessages true -C org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestReporter
java_class_path (initial): /home/ec2-user/.IntelliJIdea2016.2/config/plugins/Scala/lib/scala-plugin-runners.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/jce.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/resources.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/ec2-user/vatbox/OCRProcessingService/target/scala-2.11/test-classes:/home/ec2-user/vatbox/OCRProcessingService/target/scala-2.11/classes:/home/ec2-user/.ivy2/cache/aopalliance/aopalliance/jars/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/ec2-user/.ivy2/cache/com.jsuereth/scala-arm_2.10/jars/scala-arm_2.10-1.3.jar:/home/ec2-user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.scala-incubator.io/scala-io-file_2.10/jars/scala-io-file_2.10-0.4.3.jar:/home/ec2-user/.ivy2/cache/com.github.scala-incubator.io/scala-io-core_2.10/jars/scala-io-core_2.10-0.4.3.jar:/home/ec2-user/.ivy2/cache/xml-apis/xml-apis/jars/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar:/home/ec2-user/.ivy2/cache/xerces/xercesImpl/jars/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:/home/ec2-user/.ivy2/cache/xalan/xalan/jars/xalan-2.7.2.jar:/home/ec2-user/.ivy2/cache/xalan/serializer/jars/serializer-2.7.2.jar:/home/ec2-user/.ivy2/cache/tyrex/tyrex/jars/tyrex-1.0.1.jar:/home/ec2-user/.ivy2/cache/org.webbitserver/webbit/jars/webbit-0.4.14.jar:/home/ec2-user/.ivy2/cache/org.w3c.css/sac/jars/sac-1.3.jar:/home/ec2-user/.ivy2/cache/org.spire-math/kind-projector_2.11/jars/kind-projector_2.11-0.7.1.jar:/home/ec2-user/.ivy2/cache/org.specs2/specs2-mock_2.11/jars/specs2-mock_2.11-3.6.6.jar:/home/ec2-user/.ivy2/cache/org.specs2/specs2-matcher_2.11/jars/spec
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/home/ec2-user/AWS/go/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/home/ec2-user/AWS/go/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/home/ec2-user/AWS/go/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/home/ec2-user/AWS/go/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64
SHELL=/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:10.0

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0xabca10], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0xabca10], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x919a20], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGPIPE: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x919a20], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x919a20], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x91b050], sa_mask[0]=00100000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGHUP: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0x91c450], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x91c450], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x91c450], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

uname:Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.22 NPTL 2.22 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE infinity, NPROC 4096, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
load average:3.57 0.96 0.90

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:       32519244 kB
MemFree:         7878928 kB
MemAvailable:   22408068 kB
Buffers:            1104 kB
Cached:         14017304 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:         19328340 kB
Inactive:        3245908 kB
Active(anon):    8878736 kB
Inactive(anon):   283692 kB
Active(file):   10449604 kB
Inactive(file):  2962216 kB
Unevictable:        1112 kB
Mlocked:            1112 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:             29116 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       8649136 kB
Mapped:           359436 kB
Shmem:            606716 kB
Slab:            1631472 kB
SReclaimable:    1370736 kB
SUnreclaim:       260736 kB
KernelStack:       17520 kB
PageTables:        78420 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    16259620 kB
Committed_AS:   14331676 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       60848 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359674728 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   5951488 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      204800 kB
DirectMap2M:    33349632 kB


CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 63 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, ht, tsc, bmi1, bmi2

/proc/cpuinfo:
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 63
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x25
cpu MHz     : 2400.050
cache size  : 30720 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt
bogomips    : 4800.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 63
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x25
cpu MHz     : 2400.050
cache size  : 30720 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt
bogomips    : 4800.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 63
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x25
cpu MHz     : 2400.050
cache size  : 30720 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt
bogomips    : 4800.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 63
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x25
cpu MHz     : 2400.050
cache size  : 30720 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 6
initial apicid  : 6
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt
bogomips    : 4800.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 4
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 63
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x25
cpu MHz     : 2400.050
cache size  : 30720 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt
bogomips    : 4800.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 5
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 63
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x25
cpu MHz     : 2400.050
cache size  : 30720 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt
bogomips    : 4800.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 6
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 63
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x25
cpu MHz     : 2400.050
cache size  : 30720 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 5
initial apicid  : 5
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt
bogomips    : 4800.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 7
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 63
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x25
cpu MHz     : 2400.050
cache size  : 30720 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 7
initial apicid  : 7
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt
bogomips    : 4800.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:



Memory: 4k page, physical 32519244k(7878928k free), swap 0k(0k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.91-b14) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_91-b14), built on Apr  1 2016 00:57:21 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)

time: Sun Aug  7 04:36:38 2016
elapsed time: 16 seconds (0d 0h 0m 16s)
```

Comment: Maybe it's a problem in the `process` function? What does it do? Also try building the C++ code with debug information (ad the `-g` flag when compiling) and the stack trace might contain more information.

Comment: I am using the -g flag in the compilation. I've just more relevant information to the question. Thanks.

Comment: C++ uses null terminated strings while Java does not. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708857/call-a-static-jni-method-to-return-a-string-from-c) answer.

Comment: Thanks, I read the answer and another it pointed to and changed my use of char* to std::string (updated the question above accordingly), but the problem still recurs - the exact same error.

Comment: You need to show enough code that anyone can compile and run it on their own computer. Seems like the bug is in the function you've only shown the declaration of, not the definition.